# Cannot redeclare two functions

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I solve the following issue with the code attached? Seems that somehow Wordpress (or some kind of plugin) is calling the function twice.

```
function my_wpcf7_form_elements($html) {
    function ov3rfly_replace_include_blank($name, $text, &$html) {
        $matches = false;
        preg_match('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $html, $matches);
        if ($matches) {
            $select = str_replace('<option value="">---</option>', '<option value="">' . $text . '</option>', $matches[0]);
            $html = preg_replace('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $select, $html);
        }
    }
    ov3rfly_replace_include_blank('countrylist', 'España', $html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'my_wpcf7_form_elements');
```

> Fatal error: **Cannot redeclare ov3rfly_replace_include_blank() (previously declared in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/w/wp-content/themes/bulwark_child/functions.php:21) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/w/wp-content/themes/bulwark_child/functions.php on line 21**

Comment: simple you can not have tow same function name unless you are overloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont nest the functions - your current code declares the inner function every time the outer function is called, thereby causing the error the second time:

```
function ov3rfly_replace_include_blank($name, $text, &$html) {
    $matches = false;
    preg_match('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $html, $matches);
    if ($matches) {
        $select = str_replace('<option value="">---</option>', '<option value="">' . $text . '</option>', $matches[0]);
        $html = preg_replace('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $select, $html);
    }
}
function my_wpcf7_form_elements($html) {

    ov3rfly_replace_include_blank('countrylist', 'España', $html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'my_wpcf7_form_elements');
```

Comment: It works flawless. Thank you for the explanation and for the code provided. Indeed I'm not a PHP expert, so I did not think about the problem with the nested functions. (In 5 minutes I'll add your answer as accepted)

Comment: No problem, glad i could help you

Answer (score 1):

Check this file for re declare function as error message suggested

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/w/wp-content/themes/bulwark_child/functions.php:21
```

rename one function and see whether it working or not

Write a separate function,multiple function calling in nested function:

```
function my_wpcf7_form_elements($html) {

ov3rfly_replace_include_blank('countrylist', 'España', $html);
return $html;
}



function ov3rfly_replace_include_blank($name, $text, &$html) {
        $matches = false;
        preg_match('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $html, $matches);
    if ($matches) {
        $select = str_replace('<option value="">---</option>', '<option value="">' . $text . '</option>', $matches[0]);
        $html = preg_replace('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $select, $html);
    }
}
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'my_wpcf7_form_elements');
```